# XNA 4.0 Point Vertex Rendering

Tags: c#, xna, directx, vertex

I have a buffer of about 134 million particles and a very powerful computer to render them smoothly but I am getting an error when trying to render them as primitive lines it says I cannot render more than around 1 million. I wonder how can I do this, also if is there a better way to render this other than with lines, I'm comfortable with having 1 pixel points or anything as long as the vertices are shown all the time. I'm basically just plotting the points.

thanks.

Comment: Try posting it on GameDev.StackExchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

Split it?... :?

You can also draw in wireframe mode...

```
static readonly RasterizerState Wireframe = new RasterizerState() { FillMode = FillMode.Wireframe };


GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = Wireframe;
```

If you need to draw in both modes you can change the DepthBias too, to change the depth of the wireframe.